# Formik sets touched to true for all fields during a submit attempt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, formik

I've got an issue where trying to submit this form brings up a warning as every field is being marked as formik.touched=true - this warning should only come up when name field's are changed.

I've tried removing/adding onBlur (some online forums said that could be causing an issue), and otherwise tried console logging everywhere. Can't find out why touched is always true!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Formik always sets touched to true on submission.

https://formik.org/docs/guides/form-submission

Without seeing your validation schema, and errors, you might need to add a `.nullable()` check on your values you are passing through.

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
if (formik.submitCount === 1) {
  (data?.questions || []).forEach(({ id }) => {
    formik.setFieldTouched(id.toString(), true, true);
  });
}
```

}, [formik.submitCount]);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34763950)